# Multiple calls to viewDidLoad/loadView

Tags: iphone

In one of the views I launch programmatically, I see 5 different calls to '`loadView`/`viewdidLoad`' but I don't understand why this many are getting called. Can someone explain to me the mechanics behind this?

I launch the view in the parent `UIViewController` (part of a `TabBar` + `NavigationBar` application) instance in the following manner:

```
MainEditController *editController = [[MainEditController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainEditView" bundle:nil];           
[self.navigationController pushViewController:editController animated:YES];         
[editController release];
```

I then log `MainEditController's` `viewDidLoad` and `loadView` methods (and invoking their respective super methods).

The '`MainEditView`' nib contains 3 items: 
-File's Owner (of type `MainEditController`), 
-First Responder (of type `UIResponder`)
-View (of type `UIView`)

The view outlet is connected to the File's Owner and the View has no elements in it. What I intend to do is add several subs views to the main view and display one of the subviews based on a specific condition.

I thought both `viewDidLoad` and `loadView` would get called as many views (1 in this case) within the controller but that doesn't seem to be a valid assumption.

Comment: Is there any chance you could post your MainEditController loadView function?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Is your `loadView` method calling `[super loadView]` ? If not, the view property is likely not being set up properly, and so the next `time .view` is accessed,it tries to load it again.

Stab in the dark, but without the `loadView` method,it's hard to narrow down what might be the problem.

Comment: the documentation for loadView states: Your custom implementation of this method should not call super.

Comment: Was googling about and your answer fixed my problem :) Thanks.

Comment: Thank you! I couldn't figure out what was going on til I stepped debugged and realized this method was calling infinitely.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure if this is what you're seeing but a navigation controller will release views that are not currently visible to regain memory if a low memory warning is received by the app. When the view becomes visible again the view is recreated, which calls loadView.

Answer (score 1):

I solve same problem by removing the `-(void)loadView` method. If you create `UIViewController` without of nib file this method will automatically be added to the code.

Answer (score 0):

Set the view property of the view controller to a valid view.